# CSS Menu active item color

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

website I am talking about: http://www.formunddrang.de

When a menu item is active I am using the tag `li.selected_page` to set the color of the menu item to blue.

In order to link to a category instead of a `wp-pag`e I am using the plugin "Page Links To" which allows me add a link instead of a page to the menu. This menu item does not have the `li.selected_page` tag - it does not seem to know at all when it has been selected.

Does anyone see a way to access the status of the "Einblicke" menu item so i can make it blue when it is active?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How I understand this: You want to highlight the "Enblicke" menu when you navigate to the link it points to?

Comment: Yes - I want it to say blue when it has been selected (clicked) like the other menu items do. :(

Comment: Can you tell me what script adds the `selected_page` class to the `<li>` elements?

Comment: The menu item is generated by wpml plugin, the link-menu item by a different plugin that replaces the original menu content with the link. I don't want to modify the plugins as that would mean reediting everytime there is an update. Thanks for directing me in the right direction though - I will try to replace the menu-link plugin with some feature of wpml. (if available)
Thanks!

Comment: I personally wasn't trying to redirect you. But if you want to switch plugins, feel free to.

Answer (score 0):

You might do it via jquery:

```
var url = window.location;
// Will only work if string in href matches with location
$('#cms-nav-top-menu a[href="'+ url +'"]').addClass('active');
// Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
$('#cms-nav-top-menu a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).addClass('active');​
```

Give it a try and tell me if it's working.